# Quasistationary distribution for the Moran model

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, biology, stationary-processes

The Moran model is a model for genetic drift. Basically, it is a finite Markov chain (more precisely, a birth-death chain) with state space $S:=\{0,...,N\}$ and the following transition probabilites:

$$p_{00} = p_{NN} = 1 \ \ \text{ (absorbing states)},$$

$$ p_{i,i+1} = p_{i,i-1} = \frac{i(N-i)}{N^2},  $$

$$ p_{i,i} = 1-2p_{i,i+1}   .$$

Now we define a probability vector $q(n):=(q_1(n),...,q_{N-1}(n))$, where $q_i(n)$ is the probability of being in the state $i \in \{1,...,N-1\}$ under the condition that we have not been absorbed yet, that is,

$$ q_i(n) := \text{P}(X_n=i \ \vert \ X_n \in \{1,...,N-1\}) .$$

If we have the situation that $q(n+1)=q(n):=q$ for all times $n$, then we call $q$ a quasistationary distribution for this Markov chain.

It is precisely this $q$ that I want to find for the Moran model. I saw a proof about its existence and uniqueness, but so far I shipwrecked when I tried to explicitly compute it. Maybe one can somehow construct a nonlinear recursion and solve it. So far my ideas are very vague. Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Very clear description how to actually calculate the quasi-stationary distribution is given in Nåsell, I. 2001. Extinction and quasi-stationarity in the Verhulst logistic model. J. Theor. Biol. 211:11–27.

Comment: thank you! but in this paper I only see the case for 1 absorbing state (=$0$). The moran model has absorbing states $0$ and $N$.

Comment: A simple computation shows that if $\mu_N$ is the **uniform distribution** on $S\setminus\{0,N\}$ and if $X_0$ has distribution $\mu_N$ then $X_1$ has distribution $\frac1{N^2}(\delta_0+\delta_N)+\left(1-\frac2{N^2}\right)\mu_N$. Thus, $\mu_N$ is the quasistationary distribution of the Markov chain absorbed at $\{0,N\}$. Furthermore, if $X_0$ has distribution $\mu_N$ then the probability of non absorption at time $n$ is $\left(1-\frac2{N^2}\right)^n$.